# Single-Spa starting from scratch - angular 8 not rendering html

Tags: single-spa-angular, single-spa

I started single-spa app from scratch following:

https://medium.com/@AndrewLocke/creating-a-single-spa-web-application-4e115802f474

I wanted to use angular, so I created another app using

`ng new my-app --routing --prefix my-app`

and app was working fine, then I've added single-spa-angular by

`ng add single-spa-angular`

and application stopped rendering, even calling `angular.version` from console in dev tools returns error: angular is not defined.

How can I render this application? Or have live reloading for development?

Comment: FYI that tutorial is supersceded by create-single-spa CLI. https://single-spa.js.org/docs/create-single-spa/
And the official docs talk about why you shouldn't expect to run each app in isolation. https://single-spa.js.org/docs/recommended-setup/#local-development Like in backend microservices, apps should be developed in context of the system as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine I guess. When you add `single-spa-angular` the `angular.json` is changed (check it in git). The application gets a new rendering mode. Just continue with the tutorial and finish configuring the apps.

Also check the package.json file for new scripts. There should be one build and serve script for single-spa and a different ones for standalone use.

Comment: I've found that you can't render app in the normal way after adding single-spa, it works in root app, but not as standalone. It's bit annoying, but makes sense, since you should be developing just part of the page. Thanks for the answer :)